# MySQL query and $_GET

Tags: php

i am geting this error can someone help me what i am missing?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\kosik1.php on line 6

here is a code:

`$vysledok = mysql_query("SELECT * from produkt where IDprodukt='.$_GET['id'],$link");`

Comment: look at the single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the major security/SQL injection hole here, you're not concatenating the $_GET correctly. Here it is with the correct quotes and concatenation.

```
$vysledok = mysql_query("SELECT * from produkt where IDprodukt='".$_GET['id']."'", $link);
```

Comment: or  `$vysledok = mysql_query("SELECT * from produkt where IDprodukt={$_GET['id']},$link");` if its an integer no need for quoting

Comment: thanks its working now

Comment: You're welcome, if I helped, then please accept the answer - thank you!